# Refresh current page react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How can I refresh current page?

`this.props.history.push('/current-page')` doesn't work.

*Note: I don't want use `window.location.reload()`*

Comment: Why would you want to do a reload, maybe there is another way to do what you want

Comment: I want to re-render component to call `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: I am sure that the action you are taking inthe componentDidMount can be taken in another lifecycle function as well, without reload

Comment: Yes. that's right. I put codes to a function and call it manually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `this.forceUpdate()` in any of the methods.